# How do I create a single instance of a model through multiple html pages?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I've just gotten started with Django and I'm having trouble creating the flow I have in mind for a Q&A type application where users choose who they want to answer their question. I have a single Request model as below:

> models.py

```
class Request(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    description = models.TextField()
    responder = models.ForeignKey(Responder)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The flow would be as follows:

1. on first page, user chooses what topic they want (general knowledge, movies, etc.)
2. on second page, user fills out a form describing their question
3. on third page, user chooses a responder out of a list of available responders
4. on fourth page (if user is not logged in), they log in

So the instance of the object is created through four separate pages. What I currently have is the instance created all in one form/html page:

> forms.py

```
class UserRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields = ('user','topic','description',)

        widgets = {
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'),
            'user': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

> html page

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block content %}
 <form method="POST">
 {% bootstrap_form form %}
 {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Ask</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation to help with what I have in mind. I'd appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: [This](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html) is what you need/want.

Comment: You cannot create `Request` instance as `responder` is required.
Saving the instance using `UserRequestForm` will through you an error coming from your DB.

You need to add `null=True`on your `responder`definition.
You should and up with `responder = models.ForeignKey(Responder, null=True)`

You'll have the same issue with `created_date`, where you should use `auto_now_add=True` (See docs)[https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield]

Comment: You could create "regular" (i.e. not model forms) for the first 4 pages, store the data information in vars/session data until you get to the final form, which you could set up as a model form, have the data already received on the form as hidden fields, so they get passed back with the submit, and then the final model form would work as normal. I'm not sure if this is advisable or a terrible idea though ...

Comment: this was exactly what i needed, thank you so much!